# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in uitableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I get this error when I actually run the code (this line is the problem *var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellId) as UITableViewCell*. THis is in a UITableViewController class.

```
import UIKit

class AlarmsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var myData:Array<AnyObject> = []



override func viewDidLoad() {
    myData = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myData.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let CellId:String = "Cell"
    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellId) as UITableViewCell

    //if let ip = indexPath {
        cell.textLabel?.text = myData[indexPath.row] as? String
    //}


    return cell
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .Delete {

        //Delete row from data source
        //if let tv = tableView? {
            myData.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)


    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {

    }
}


}
```

Comment: Did you set the cell identifier for your prototype cell ?

Comment: i'm a noob to swift and ios, i updated the question with my entire class. Does it help?

Comment: Do you have your tableview controller in storyboard ? Did you have a prototype cell in the storyboard ? If yes did you set the reuseIdentifier for that ?

Comment: Maybe it's because your cell doesn't have a "textLabel" or you didn't set the right reuse identifier in interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

In the interface builder, select the TableViewController with which you are working with. Then, select the prototype cell and set its style to "Basic". Finally, set the cells reuse identifier to Cell.